# What is the operating mechanism when Google V8 pre-parses a nested function?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, compilation, v8

I know about the pre-parsing and full-parsing of V8. Due to the lazying pasring，if the parser encounters a function declaration, it will skip the code inside the function, and will not generate AST and bytecode for it, but only generate the AST and bytecode of the top-level code. Instead, When parsing the top-level code encounters a function, the pre-parser will do a quick pre-parsing of the function.The purpose is to: Determine whether there is a syntax error in the current function, and if found, it will be thrown. Check if the function internally refers to the external variable. If it is, the external variable is copied to the heap, and the next time the function is executed, the reference in the heap is directly used.

Take the following code as an example, Apparently 't' has a closure(a) {i: 1} at the head of its [[Scopes]](You can run this code on Chrome), my question is that 'a' is a three-layer-nested function, when 'a' is pre-parsed for the first time on global environment, what is the algorithm that pre-parser finds the variable referred by the internal functions in function 'a', recursively or by other way? If it is recursive, first find function b, then scan the functions inside b which is function c, will c be parsed 2 more times before it is really called?

```
function a() {
    let i = 1;
    function b(){
        function c() {
            console.log(i);
        }
        return c;
    }
    return b;
}
let t = a();
console.dir(t);
```

Comment: [I think this is a duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63846859/pre-parsing-and-execution-context), which has a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is answered in https://v8.dev/blog/preparser#variable-allocation.

> To avoid the nonlinear performance overhead, we perform full scope resolution even during preparsing. We store enough metadata so we can later simply skip inner functions, rather than having to re-preparse them. One way would be to store variable names referenced by inner functions. This is expensive to store and requires us to still duplicate work: we have already performed variable resolution during preparse.

> Instead, we serialize where variables are allocated as a dense array of flags per variable. When we lazy-parse a function, variables are recreated in the same order as the preparser saw them, and we can simply apply the metadata to the variables.

So in my understanding, in the first "preparse" of `a` it will find the variable `i`, will also scan through `b` and `c` and will find a usage of `i` which marks it as heap allocated. Afterwards `a` can be executed without having further parsed `b` and `c`, and if they are ever executed `i` will already be heap allocated and can be used by the inner function.